# Angularjs controller function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to Angularjs. I created a small program to take input on form-submit and add it to json data using a controller function.

It seems like a small error in program but I am unable to locate it.

Please help: below are my **angjs.html**( which has the form defined in it ), and **app.js**( for the controllers and json data ):

**angjs.html**

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="loginController as login">
        <div ng-repeat="user in login.users">
            <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
            <h3>{{user.password}}</h3>
        </div>
        <form name="loginUser" ng-controller="FeedDataController as feedCtrl" ng-submit="feedCtrl.addUser(user)">
            <!-- Live preview -->
            <div>
                <h2>{{feedCtrl.user.username}}</h2>
                <h3>{{feedCtrl.user.password}}</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- form submit -->
            <input type="text" ng-model="feedCtrl.user.username" name="username" /><br />
            <input type="text" ng-model="feedCtrl.user.password" name="password" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="GO" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('login',[]);

app.controller('loginController',function(){
    this.users = user;
});

app.controller('FeedDataController',function(){
    this.user={};
    this.addUser=function(user){
        user.push(this.user);
        this.user={};
    };
});

var user = [
{username: 'Azurite',    password: 'hello',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  },
{username: 'Blinge',    password: 'right',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  }
];
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: Have you defined your angular app anywhere in the angjs.html provided? Your given `<div>`  should be enclosed in the div containing `ng-app`.

Comment: there is no error but just addUser function is not working! :(

Comment: @Jagrut: Yes I have defined ng-app on my <html> tag. All divs are contained in it only.

Comment: You are resetting the `this.user` in `addUser()` function. You need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo between user and users

plunker  : http://plnkr.co/edit/tn5pwxidy0uf3rnlGUHT?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('login',[]);

app.controller('loginController',function(){
    this.users = users;
});

app.controller('FeedDataController',function(){
    this.user={};
    this.addUser=function(){
        users.push(this.user);
        this.user={};
    };
});

var users = [
  {username: 'Azurite',    password: 'hello',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  },
  {username: 'Blinge',    password: 'right',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  }
];
});
```

Comment: I have ng-app defined with html tag as: <html ng-app="..">

Comment: i changed my answer; did you have a typo on user.push(this.user); ?? 
it should be `users.push(this.user);`

Comment: All code is in front of you. I did it same as you suggest. No typo there

Comment: here is what console is saying though:
`TypeError: user.push is not a function
    at addUser (app.js:12)
    at angular.js:12345
    at f (angular.js:21438)
    at l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21443)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.js:3014)`

Comment: I see its working there. Exactly what I wanted and I see you passed "window.angular"  to the all enclosing function. Was THAT the problem?

Comment: no. this is just for making the plunker work. you use `user` instead of `users` so when you add a new one it was erasing the list

Comment: I tried your plunker code replacing mine.
This is what console says now:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at addUser (app.js:12)
    at angular.js:12345
    at f (angular.js:21438)
    at l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21443)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.js:3014)`

Comment: and I did replace "user with "users" in app.js

Comment: if you put the `var users = [..]` array in `FeedDataController` ?

Comment: oh yes.. Thank you so much for your patience with me. It is working as you pointed it out! :)

Comment: glad it help. you should not declare var outside any controller in the global scope. if you want to share data between controller the bests ways are service ( singleton ) , or $rootscope. If the answer work you can make it a valid reponse

Answer (score 0):

In `ng-submit="feedCtrl.addUser(user)"` you use `user`, which is undefined. Change to `ng-submit="feedCtrl.addUser(feedCtrl.user)"`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly closed you IIFE function in app.js:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('login', []);

app.controller('loginController',function(){
    //var vm = this;
    this.users = user;
});

app.controller('FeedDataController',function(){
    //var vm = this;    
    this.user={};
    this.addUser=function(user){
        user.push(this.user);
        this.user={};
    };
});

var user = [
{username: 'Azurite',    password: 'hello',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  },
{username: 'Blinge',    password: 'right',    canPurchase: false,    soldOut: true  }
];

})();
```

Comment: here is what console is saying though:
`TypeError: user.push is not a function
    at addUser (app.js:12)
    at angular.js:12345
    at f (angular.js:21438)
    at l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21443)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.js:3014)`

Comment: you are mixing `user`, `this.user`  and `users`